# relative path doesn't work with paths

Tags: path, requirejs, relative-path

I'm having a problem with relative paths in requirejs.

First of all, I have the following structure. I'm running it with a virtual host (os.com) and the path is os.com/test

[image]

**index.html**

```
<script data-main="config" src="require.js"></script>
```

**config.js**

```
require.config({

  baseUrl: "./apps",
  deps: ['ui'],
  paths: {
    ui: 'ui/ui',
    system: 'system/system',
    core: 'core/core'
  }


});
```

**ui.js**

```
define(['./class/menuBuilder',"./class/window"], function(menuBuilder, windowBuilder){


    return {
        menuBuilder: menuBuilder,
        windowBuilder: windowBuilder
    }

});
```

When I run it, I get the following errors.

```
GET http://os.com/test/apps/class/menuBuilder.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://os.com/test/apps/class/window.js 404 (Not Found)
```

If I take out 'ui' property from the 'paths' property then change deps to ['ui/ui'], it works, but I would like to use paths.

**Changed config.js**

```
require.config({

  baseUrl: "./apps",
  deps: ['ui/ui'],
  paths: {
    system: 'system/system',
    core: 'core/core'
  }


});
```

How do I change my config to make paths and relative path work together?

Answer (score 12):

I had similar problem. I didn't have deps:'ui' part in my configuration, just the path setting, but still the relative module reference ('./class/menuBuilder') would not work from the module loaded with path ("ui: 'ui/ui'") and would use baseUrl instead. To solve it, I defined 'ui' as a package:

```
require.config({

  baseUrl: "./apps",
  deps: ['ui'],
  paths: {
    system: 'system/system',
    core: 'core/core'
  },
  packages : [
    { 
        name: 'ui',
        location : 'ui',
        main : 'ui'
    },
  ]

});
```

In this case require will load relatively-pathed modules correctly.

Here is a useful post: [Relative paths with RequireJS modules/packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302284/relative-paths-with-requirejs-modules-packages)

Answer (score 4):

The solution here is to use map configuration, not paths configuration. Paths configurations should only be used for folders, not modules themselves. Map configurations apply to individual modules.

So try:

```
require.config({
  map: {
    '*': {
      'ui': 'ui/ui'
    }
  }
});
```