# Javascript module with requirejs with local path

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am building a JavaScript module. Can load the first file in the module no problem. From there I want to load other files, but requirejs follows the path from the index. I want the functions in the module to be available in global scope. The structure is like this:

index.html:

```
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

app.js:

```
requirejs([ "../../modules/foo" ], function(util) {
});
```

modules/foo.js:

```
requirejs([ "bar" ], function(util) {
});
```

That gives the error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, well, yes, if you look from app.js you will not find it. **How to force requirejs to load from the module?**

These posts are probably related, but I can't wrap my head around it:

[RequireJS relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548369/requirejs-relative-paths)

[Using require with relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491952/using-require-with-relative-paths)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I found around this: Create a minified && uglified && required file, where all other files are loaded into. Also know as the [RequireJS Optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#basics).